# Using pivot_wider in R to reshape biomarkHD data?

Tags: r, pivot-table, reshape

I have the following snippet of my dataframe.  The values aren't important.  I am trying to get it to wide form using pivot_wider.

```
Dataset
id_1 <- c("S78-A01", "S78-A04", "S90-A01", "S90-A04", "S82-A01", "S82-A04", "S94-A01", "S94-A04", "S75-A01", "S75-A04", "S87-A01", "S87-A04")
id_2 <- c("CB-2_1:1024", "CB-2_1:1024", "CB-2_1:1024", "CB-2_1:1024", "CB-2_1:128", "CB-2_1:128", "CB-2_1:128", "CB-2_1:128", "CB-2_1:16", "CB-2_1:16", "CB-2_1:16", "CB-2_1:16")
Gene <- c("AIM2", "AIM2", "AIM2", "AIM2", "AIM2", "AIM2", "AIM2", "AIM2", "AIM2", "C1QB", "C1QB", "C1QB")
value1 <- c(-1.9975984661369099, 4.7789368498721396 , 3.3080754647069801, 6.9507934374320604, 2.55279730894866, 1.38567349551152, 1.99, 4.5115336458523103, 3.2588723737573799, 6.9433118002602097, 2.5897834603682202, 1.4031532547429899)

df <- data.frame(id1 =id_1, 
id2=id_2, 
Gene=Gene,
value1=value1)

# Pivot
df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = c("id2","Gene"),
                   values_from =  "value1")
```

However when I pivot I get the data as such with the headers like the below :

| id1 | CB-2_1:1024_AIM2 | CB-2_1:128_AIM2 | CB-2_1:16_AIM2 | CB-2_1:16_C1QB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S78-A01 | -2 | NA | NA | NA |
| S78-A04 | 4.78 | NA | NA | NA |

What I want is it in the form of the below.  I will take as close to that as I can get.  The data is too large too do manually with 9218 rows.  Any ideas of where I am pivoting wrong?  DOes what I want to do even make sense with  pivot?

| id2 | gene | val1 | val2 | val3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CB-2_1:1024 | AIM2 | -1.997589 | 4.778937 | 3.308075 |
| CB-2_1:128 | AIM2 | 2.552797 | 2.589783 | 1.403153 |
| CB-2_1:16 | C1QB | 6.943312 | 1.385673 | 1.990000 |

Comment: It isn't clear (to me) where your `val1`, `val2`, `val3` come from. What are the _actual_ values of `x`, `y`, `z`, etc?

Comment: They should be -1.997598, 4.778937 and 3.308075.  I will modify the question to make it clearer. Sorry

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - your desired output has `-1.997589, 4.778937, 3.308075` all associated with `S78-A01`  but in your source data these are associated with different ids ("S78-A01", "S78-A04", "S90-A01") - it looks like you want them grouped by "gene" rather than by id1, is that right?

Comment: Yeah, that is the problem I am getting into.  They do come from different id1, I do want them grouped by the gene.  Do I leave out the id1?  The combination of id2 and gene is what makes them unique.  I could leave out the id1 if necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id2, Gene) %>%
  mutate(rn = paste0("value", row_number())) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(c(id2, Gene), names_from = "rn", values_from = "value1")
# # A tibble: 4 x 6
#   id2         Gene  value1 value2 value3 value4
#   <chr>       <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 CB-2_1:1024 AIM2   -2.00   4.78   3.31   6.95
# 2 CB-2_1:128  AIM2    2.55   1.39   1.99   4.51
# 3 CB-2_1:16   AIM2    3.26  NA     NA     NA   
# 4 CB-2_1:16   C1QB    6.94   2.59   1.40  NA
```

Comment: That is really close and thanks but it is not quite what I mean.  I am sorry for being so unclear.  Let's see if I can praise it better.  
# # A tibble: 2 x 10
#   Gene  value1 value2 value3 

# 1 CB-2_1:1024 AIM2   -2.00   4.78   3.31  
# 2  CB-2_1:128 AIM2  2.6 1.4 2
# 3  CB-2_1:16 C1QB    6.94   2.59   1.40

Comment: Your sample output is broken: 6 columns in row 1, 5 columns in row 2. See my edit, does that work?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to make something broken.  Thanks so much.  This is what I am looking for!  That is perfect.  I have no idea how you did it but this internet stranger loves you!

Comment: It was broken until you edited it, it's likely I just caught it mid-edit. Thanks for fixing it and working through this. Glad it helps!